# Prevent mounting of a specific volume when connecting an external drive

Tags: macos, external-disk, partition

I've got an external drive with 3 volumes on it.
All of them are mounted upon connecting the external drive to my Mac.

I want one of these 3 volumes to not be mounted when I connect it.
Is that somehow possible?

Comment: You can flag a question as duplicate by clicking on the flag link (below the tags) and indicating the reason. I've done it for this one.

Comment: I did it as well.